# InfoPath: Passing nodes to C# from form rules

Tags: xpath, infopath

I have just discovered the very useful `xdExtension` keyword which allows you to execute code directly from a form rule. However any nodes passed into the called function are of type `ComObject` and there doesn't seem to be a way to cast them into an `XPathNavigator` or other useful construct from within C#.

Rule condition:

```
xdExtension:Myfunction(../my:Node)
```

This should allow me to manipulate the passed node in C#, but instead I just get a `ComObject` that can't be cast to anything.

Is there any way to pass something that C# can identify as an `XPathNode`?